# Add button at the end of label

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I'm having a `collectionviewCell` that looks like so...

[collectionviewCell shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hJHV.png)

The constraints for the above `collectionviewCell` is `Leading, trailing, Top, Bottom`

The cross button above deletes each element. Now I want to position the cross button at the end of the label so that it'll always appear at the end of each text in the label no matter what the length of the text within the label is and without cropping the label.

If I drag the cross button beside the label, then the label goes out of the collectionview cell if the text within the label is long..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about constraining the button the trailing edge, setting a fixed width on it and the constrain the trailing edge of the label to the leading edge of the button? That way the button will never be overlapped by the label and if the text of the label is too long only the text will truncated

Comment: actually I didn't want the text also to get truncated..

Comment: Well, then leave the trailing constraint on the button to the view's edge. But in that case it will clip outside of the view if the text is too long. Maybe I misunderstood your question though

Comment: alternatively, how about letting the label move text to the next line if it's too long? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using constraint link the `trailing` label to the `Leading` of the `button` and the `trailing` button to the `trailing` of the `collectionviewCell` for the button you can give it a `height` and `width` constraint.

If the label text is too long you can set the number of lines to 0 which means as much numbers of lines needed otherwise you can set it to the number of lines desired then the text truncated if it's too long.